# Average ranks of abelian surfaces

Tags: nt.number-theory, abelian-varieties

Most people nowadays believe that over a fixed global field, $50$% of the elliptic curves have $0$ rank, $50$% have rank $1$, and $0$% have higher rank. A significant advance in this direction has been Bhargava and Shankar's proof that for elliptic curves over $\mathbb{Q}$, the rank is bounded on average (indeed, not just the Mordell-Weil rank, but even the $2$-Selmer rank).

Has anybody put forth a similar guess for the ranks of higher dimensional abelian varieties? If so, what is the rationale behind such a guess? I am asking about the precise statistical distribution of ranks.

Comment: I don't know about a general conjecture, but for instance for hyperelliptic curves with a rational Weierstrass point, Bhargava and Gross have a bound for the average rank of the Jacobian. See http://arxiv.org/pdf/1208.1007.pdf

Comment: By the way, the Bhargava-Gross bound on the number of points on such curves has been greatly improved by Bjorn Poonen and Michael Stoll in *Chabauty's method proves that most odd degree hyperelliptic curves have only one rational point* (http://arxiv.org/abs/1302.0061). 

Comment: Thank you very much for those references. The bounds for the hyperelliptic Jacobians in the Bhargava-Gross paper being the same as for elliptic curves, it could perhaps not be too wild to believe that (contrary to what I expected) the same distribution persists for abelian varieties: for a given global field $F$ and a given dimension $g$, that $50$% of the $g$-dimensional abelian varieties over $F$ have $0$ rank, $50$% have rank $1$, and $0$% have higher rank?

Comment: It might be argued that jacobians of hyperelliptic curves (and indeed jacobians of all curves) form only a small (even negligible) portion of abelian varieties of any given high enough genus.

Comment: Indeed they do, and it is not at all clear what the answer should be. 

Comment: In the case of genus 2, a generic abelian surface is the jacobian of an hyperelliptic curve, at least over the algebraic closure.

Comment: By the way, how should one order abelian varieties of given dimension over the rationals: by conductor, by Faltings height? Are there other convenient orderings?

Comment: My implicit assumption was by Faltings height. It seems not improbable, though, that the ordering them by conductor would give the same average.[?] 

Comment: Here is another example of possible bias when considering special families of abelian varieties : consider the abelian varieties $A_f$ associated to weight 2 newforms $f$. The Mordell-Weil group $A_f(\mathbf{Q})$ is a module over the Hecke algebra which is an order of a number field of degree $d=\dim A_f$. Thus in this setting I think one expects the average rank to be $d/2$. It would be nice to have a clean conjecture for a generic abelian variety over a number field (a generic abelian variety has trivial ring of endomorphisms, unlike $A_f$).

Comment: BTW, do you have a reference for the belief about the average rank of elliptic curves over a given global field?

Comment: Here is one reference: the paper by Poonen and Rains, "Random maximal isotropic subspaces and Selmer groups." By the way, a trivial remark: you also get the same expectation $d/2$ within the very special family of products of elliptic curves. I wonder which of these two biases is closer to the truth.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I guess we may ask about the rank distribution among abelian varieties with given Mumford-Tate group.

Comment: The paper "Some heuristics on elliptic curves" (sec 4), has a discussion of ordering by discriminant versus conductor, and the author concludes they should all be the same for the therein purposes (rank 2 curves). In 3.4 (second paragraph), the naive height and discriminant distinction is glossed barely. The paper does not describe Faltings height explicitly, though a real period (not volume) occurs in the analysis of rank estimates and $L$-function vanishings. There is an arXiv preprint, but it lacks some later revisions, I detect. http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/~watkins/papers/heur.pdf
